# Access denied for mysql, Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I've configured a `.env` file just as stated in the tuts, but I still keep on getting `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

My credentials are correct as it would properly authenticate when I use MAMP's mysql via terminal.

Could anyone enlighten me on this? your knowledge would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/321903/resetting-forgotten-phpmyadmin-password?newreg=9c01dd2efc184ee79c939efea394089e


This is pretty much the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the terminal to revert any changes.

– `mysql -u root`

– `UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD(‘Enter Your New Password HERE’) WHERE user=”root”;`

You might need to flush privilages,

– `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

Then just restart your MySQL server.

Note: As you are on local then no need to put any password. you can leave password as empty.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would I need to refresh my credentials? they work perfectly fine in MAMP's mysql via terminal.

Comment: You can use same password if exists.